# window.history.back() but only when that wont take the user away from current site

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, html5-history

Title says it all pretty much. I.e. I need to call that to get the user to the previous location they were in, but only when it does not take them away from our site.

E.g.

```
mysite.com/#/foo - > 
mysite.com/#/bar - > 
back is triggered - >
user ends back to mysite.com/#/foo
```

where as if user goes straight to

```
mysite.com/#/bar - > 
back is triggered - >
user is back to whatever site they were first in.
```

Comment: use `document.referrer` to get and compare the previus url and compare with the current, so let user back or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple function for that:

```
function returnBack(){

    // If last visited page before this page is in your domain
    if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.host) >= 0)
    {
        window.history.back()
    }
    else {
        // If last page is not in your domain, do your logic here..
    }

}
```

Comment: You can substitute *'mysite.com'* with `window.location.host`

Comment: Yesssss perfect

Comment: Actually no, apparently document.referrer does not change when only location hashes are changed... Sigh..

Comment: @Seppo420 - I think you need use HTML5 History API instead

Comment: @xYundy what part of it exactly? Didnt find anything too relevant